# Fragment getting detached from Activity without obvious reason

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, lifecycle

My problem: When i close my app via long-pressing home button (Samsung S4) in the app manager, everything works fine on the next startup.

But, when i close the app in onBackPressed when its time to close it, i get a crash on the next start of the app, because "getActivty" returns null.

I checked multiple times which lifecycle methods get called during these two scenarios, and wasn't able to find any difference.

Also, i use the piece of code producing the crash in another fragment, but there it works fine.

The question is: Why returns getActivity null, when the Activity is definitely alive? Better said, why is my fragment not attached to the Activity anymore?

Relevant code (i hope)

init of main fragment:

```
    //Declared globally in Activity
    FirstFragment fr; 

    //In activities onCreate
    fr = new FirstFragment();
    getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.main_fragment, fr, "first")
            .setTransitionStyle(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
            .addToBackStack("")
            .commit();
```

Switching to the second fragment is done with this method (Where the parameter "Object fragment" is "new SecondFragment")

```
public void changeFragment(Object fragment, String name, boolean stayMain) {
    if (!stayMain) {
        findViewById(R.id.title_bar_left_button).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_back);
        findViewById(R.id.title_bar_left_button).setOnClickListener(backToMainListener);
    }

    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.navTitle)).setText(name);

    findViewById(R.id.title_bar_right_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);

    getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.main_fragment, (Fragment)fragment, name)
            .setTransitionStyle(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
            .addToBackStack("")
            .commit();
}
```

Code causing the crash: (since getActivity returns null in described scenario

```
 Context c = this.getActivity();

 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you have thread or service running from the application?

Comment: The crash causing code is called from a Broadcastreceiver. But as mentioned, in the second fragment it works

Comment: Thinking about this, in the second fragment its called in onClick. But nevertheless this is no reason for the fragment being detached. pls help

Comment: Have you stopped the Broadcastreceiver @ onStop/onDestroy?

Comment: can you post a build up code towards the npe codeline?

Comment: Unregistering the receiver causes in a crash, stating that it is not registered. What is a build up code?